# Integer value changes during insertion to array

Tags: c, arrays, netbeans

I am having some weird problems with my code and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm relatively new to C-language, so I'd really appreciate if someone could point out if I'm doing something stupid.

I'm trying to read data from a file into two dimensional array of type *state*. Type state is defined as follows:

```
typedef uint8_t state [4][4];
```

I have defined method *read_block* that gets the file pointer as parameter and returns pointer two dimensional type *state* array which contains first 16 bytes from that file.

```
state* read_block(FILE *fp) {
    state *arr = (state*) malloc(sizeof (state));
    uint8_t *temp = (uint8_t*) malloc(sizeof (uint8_t)*16);

    fread(temp, 16, 1, fp);

    /*
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
        printf("%u ", temp[y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    */

    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            /*
            printf("%u ", temp[n]);
            */
            *arr[i][j] = temp[n];
            n++;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Code compiles and runs ok, but the type *state* array that method returns always contains one wrong value. Specifically, the value in position [3][0] is always wrong.

The test file I'm trying to read contains numbers:

```
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
```

I decided to check if the values are read right and if I remove comments around printf lines I get as output:

```
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 3 1 2 3
```

In which the first line is exactly correct (that is printed right after *fread()*), but for some reason the second line is incorrect (that is printed when inserting values into *arr*).

I can't figure out what is causing this. I've also tried reading values one byte at time with *fread*, but the same value keeps being wrong. I'm using NetBeans, so I'm not sure if this is somehow being caused by it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running into operator precedence.

```
*arr[i][j]
```

is the same as

```
*(arr[i][j])   // or arr[i][j][0]
```

This is the same only if `i == 0`, i.e. in the first line.

What you want is

```
(*arr)[i][j]
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not really a good idea to hide an array behind a typedef. This is the root of the problem, since `arr` is actually an array pointer of type `uint8_t (*)[4][4]`. And when de-referencing an array pointer you have to first take the contents of the pointer to get the array, then after access a specific index. That is, you will have to do `(*arr)[i][j]` rather than `*arr[i][j]`.

To avoid that fishy syntax in turn, you could use a trick and declare an array pointer to the outermost dimension: `uint8_t(*)[4]`. Then you can suddenly type `arr[i][j]` instead. `arr[i]` then means do pointer arithmetic on a `uint8_t(*)[4]` type, and then in the obtained result you can access a specific array index, `[j]`.

In addition to the operator precedence issue, you probably want to store data directly into the array. There's no reason why you can't do `fread(arr, 16, 1, fp);`, since you are using that array in the same order as it is allocated.

I haven't tested it, but you should be able to replace the whole function with this:

```
void read_block(FILE* fp, uint8_t (*arr)[4][4]) 
{
  const size_t size = sizeof(uint8_t[4][4]);
  *arr = malloc(size);
  fread(*arr, size, 1, fp);
}
```